# WQL query for notification on process creation/termination

Tags: c++, winapi, process, wql

I have a `WQL` query as follows that lists all the running processes of my system.

```
ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"), 
        bstr_t("SELECT * " 
            "FROM  Win32_Process"), 
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);
```

Now how should I write a `WQL` query to get notification on process creation and termination using `C++`. I tried `"SELECT * FROM  __InstanceCreationEvent"`, `"SELECT * FROM  Win32_ProcessStartTrace"`,etc.. But it didnot work. Please help.

Comment: No one to help ??? :(

Comment: Please be patient. I don't know the answer, but someone else might. Not all of us are active all the time.